# how do i get my western digital external drive to work on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: external-hdd

i used this 1 TB external device for long time on windows, and i put a password for my device also, how can i get it to work on Ubuntu?

my device is listed when i type in *lsusb*

but in windows there was this "**Unlocker.exe**" so i could type my password and then access my external HDD , now i have no idea how to access my HDD on Ubuntu.

please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, it is not possible even via wine.

You need disable password protection in windows system so that you can use it in ubuntu.

Comment: thank you, i disabled the password, and now it works perfectly